# What is the period of Gamma Cassiopeiae?

Tags: variable-star, estimate

[Gamma Cassiopeiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_Cassiopeiae) is a variable star whose magnitude changes between 1.6 and 3. On what timescale does it vary?

The Wikipedia page says that it is irregular, but what is the timescale of its variations? Less than a day? A month? Several years? On average, how long would I have to wait before noticing a variation in its brightness?

Answer (score 2):

The variation isn't periodic. The light curve below ([from aavso](https://www.aavso.org/vsots_gammacas)) shows the period from 1960.

[image]

In the 1930s the star also had an episode of fading and brightening, It faded by about a magnitude over about 150 days. ([source](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1940AJ.....49...29A))